# sftp permission denied error occured after try to remove the file

Tags: go, sftp

I am trying to copy files from "dir" to a "oldDir" and remove the original files in "dir" after I upload the files to somewhere else. I can do all the steps except I cannot remove the original file.

I checked both the file and the root directory's permission code are -rwxrwxrwx, which should be fine for me to remove the file.

```
func UpdateItemAndRemoveOldOne (sConfig sftp.Config) (err error) {
    var (
        path    = "./newDir/"
        oldPath = "./oldDir/"
        file    *s.File
        b       []byte
        config  db.Config
    )

    ids, err := db.FindIDs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot get the list of items")
        return
    }

    dir, err := sConfig.Client.ReadDir("./newDir")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot read directory")
        return
    }
    oldDir, err := sConfig.Client.ReadDir("./oldDir")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot read old directory")
        return
    }

    for _, f := range dir {
        name := f.Name()
        exist := false
        for _, oldF := range oldDir {
            if name == oldF.Name() {
                exist = true
                break
            }
        }
        if exist {
            continue
        }

        if segments := strings.Split(name, "."); len(segments) != 3 {
            log.Println("Invalid file name:", name)
        } else if config, err = db.FindConfigByDevID(strings.ToLower(segments[1])); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot find the item by last 4 char of id, err:", err)

        } else if file, err = sConfig.Client.Open(path + name); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot open "+path+name+" , err:", err)
        } else if b, err = ioutil.ReadAll(file); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot read "+path+name+" , err:", err)
        } else if err = closeFile(file); err != nil {
            log.Println(file + " cannot closed")
        } else if err = upload(getUploadPath(1, config.ID)+name, b); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot upload file:", name, ", err:", err)
        } else if file, err = sConfig.Client.Create(oldPath + name); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot create file after uploaded:", name, ", err:", err)
        } else if _, err = file.Write(b); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot write file after uploaded:", name, ", err:", err)
        } else if err = closeFile(file); err != nil {
            log.Println(file + " cannot closed")
        } else if _, err = sCongif.Client.Remove(path + name); err != nil {
            log.Println("Cannot remove file after uploaded:", name, ", err:", err)
        } else {
            log.Println("uploaded:", name)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

I have got error sftp: "Permission denied" (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED)
I tried to just test the remove function and I could remove some files, but some files I still got this error, but I pretty sure that they have the same file permission code.

Problem solved:
found out that I had opened the file without closing it. And somehow the file is still opened by FreeSSHDService. That's why I could not remove the file.

Comment: Deleting a file is a write operation on the containing directory (in this case newDir). The permissions of the file to be deleted and the root directory are irrelevant.

Comment: is there any way I can remove the file that has opened before? It seems that once I opened it, I am not able to remove the file.